# "Add To Cart" Woocommerce Button Not Changing To "Add To Basket" Even With functions.php Coding

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce, text

I have tried every bit of code under the sun but I can't get the "Add To Cart" button text changed to "Add To Basket" on a standard product page in a standard Woocommerce setup. See link for page example below showing the "add to cart" button text I want to change.

https://www.charliecustards.co.uk/product/new-orleans-brogue-boot-in-mocha-calf-suede/

I have tried the following code shown in image, in the functions.php file (child theme) so no idea why this is not working as the code makes sense to me?

[image: code not working]I am obviously missing something here but not sure what, all help greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

in order to change product Add to cart button text you have to add in your functions.php

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'woocommerce_custom_add_to_cart_button_text' ); 
function woocommerce_custom_add_to_cart_button_text() {
    return __( 'Buy Now', 'woocommerce' ); 
}
```

your mentioned filter will work only with product archive page.

Comment: Thank you for the response, appreciated. I tried your code and it did not work?  As you can see at the following link it still says "ADD TO CART" instead of "Add To Basket" (i changed the buy now in your code to add to basket).

https://www.charliecustards.co.uk/product/new-orleans-brogue-boot-in-mocha-calf-suede/